# Possible to index 1M docs/sec in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, elasticsearch-2.0

I am trying to optimize indexing speed in ElasticSearch, as we are constantly reindexing indexes every hour, and so the faster we are able to re-index our data, the less of a lag we can achieve.

I came across this article which talks about reaching a re-indexing throughput of 100K: https://thoughts.t37.net/how-we-reindexed-36-billions-documents-in-5-days-within-the-same-elasticsearch-cluster-cd9c054d1db8#.4w3kl9ebf, and this StackOverflow question which achieves higher: [ElasticSearch - high indexing throughput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27388521/elasticsearch-high-indexing-throughput).

My question is whether it is possible to achieve a sustained indexing throughput of 1 million documents per second, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will depend on a few factors, but why should it be impossible? Here are a few key factors, that will speed up the indexing process:

- size of the documents (smaller is faster)
- number of cores and size of memory (more is faster)
- number of machines (more is faster)
- number of replicas (fewer is faster)

As an example, with small documents and a single eight core machine, I was able to [index at about 70k-120k docs/s](https://asciinema.org/a/dxlsrgpcu9axuuql4jr3m30xm?autoplay=1). Throw in a few more cores or machines and you could approach 1M docs/s.

---

Update: Another test run with [Elasticsearch 6.1.0](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-6-1-0-released), on a single 32-core [E5](https://ark.intel.com/products/83361/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2667-v3-20M-Cache-3_20-GHz), with 64G JVM heap. Here, [esbulk](https://github.com/miku/esbulk) could index about 330000 docs/s, using 10M small documents of sizes 20-40 bytes.

---

Disclaimer: I wrote [esbulk](https://github.com/miku/esbulk). The README contains a few [measurements](https://github.com/miku/esbulk#measurements) - maximum at the moment is at about 300k docs/s.